# Firebase Structure: Flat and Asymmetical or Break Out

Tags: firebase

I'm looking to use Firebase (and AngularJS) for a music festival site that contains different types of events. I'm new to designing data structures hierarchically and have read many of the primers on Stackoverflow and the firebase blog, which have been helpful to leading me to this question.

This music festival has music events, movie events, lecture events, etc, all which will have some overlapping attributes (name, date, description) but also different attributes depending on the event type. Based on what I know about structuring data in Firebase, I'm considering two models so far:

### Model 1 - Flat and Asymmetical:

```
ROOT
|
+--EVENTS
    |
    +-- EventID_1
    |    |-- EventType: "Music"
    |    |-- Name: "The Beatles"
    |    |-- Description: "Description goes here."
    |    |-- Date: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
    |    |-- Mp3Url: "http://some.music.url"
    |    |-- OtherMusicOnlyAttrib: "..."
    |
    +-- EventID_2
    |    |-- EventType: "Movie"
    |    |-- Name: "A Light That Never Goes Out"
    |    |-- Description: "Description goes here."
    |    |-- Date: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
    |    |-- YouTubePreview: "http://youtube.com/somevideo"
    |    |-- OtherMovieOnlyAttrib: "..."
    |
    +-- EventID_3
        |-- EventType: "Lecture"
        |-- Name: "Cornelius Northshire"
        |-- Description: "Summary of lecture topic."
        |-- Date: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
        |-- Bio: "Biography of lecturer."
        |-- OtherLectureOnlyAttrib: "..."
```

**Benefit:** The obvious and immediate benefit of this structure is that all events are located at one Firebase URL.  Creating a master schedule view listing all events at once is fairly trivial. I could then filter on the client side by `EventType` for a music only view or if a user wishes to see only music or only movies on the master schedule.

**Drawbacks:** Something feels wrong about having an asymmetrical model. I'm also some what concerned about the speed of filtering on the client side as there will probably be ~500 entries, but maybe it won't be a problem.

### Model 2 - Broken Out:

```
ROOT
|
+-- EVENTS
     |
     +-- MUSIC
     |    |
     |    +-- MusicEventID_1
     |         |
     |         |-- Name: "The Beatles"
     |         |-- Description: "Description goes here."
     |         |-- Date: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
     |         |-- Mp3Url: "http://some.music.url"
     |         |-- OtherMusicAttrib: "..."
     |
     +-- MOVIES
     |    |
     |    +-- MovieEventID_1
     |         |
     |         |-- Name: "A Light That Never Goes Out"
     |         |-- Description: "Description goes here."
     |         |-- Date: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
     |         |-- YouTubePreview: "http://youtube.com/somevideo"
     |         |-- OtherMovieAttrib: "..."
     |
     +-- LECTURES
          |
          +-- LectureEventID_1
               |
               |-- Name: "Cornelius Northshire"
               |-- Description: "Summary of lecture topic."
               |-- Date: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
               |-- Bio: "Biography of lecturer."
               |-- OtherLectureAttrib: "..."
```

**Benefit:** Each event type has its own Firebase url. As a result client side event filtering for a music only view wouldn't be necessary.  Also each event model would be consistent for each item, which may make it slightly easier for displaying event detail views.

**Drawbacks:** A master schedule view listing all the event types (possibly) becomes more difficult. I'm not familiar with a good way to iterate over all the event types and their child events, although I'm sure it's possible.

### Conclusion:

I would like to learn something here.  If anyone has feedback on which way would be better (and I'm open to what, "better" means), I would be grateful.  Of course I'm also open to a 3rd option should it present itself. I'm hoping to prevent myself from regretting the decision later on.  I hope to go down the path that allows for the most flexibility moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Firebird (I always work on SQL Server) but i think what you ask is a general database design question. I would use a variant of the first option you post. Specially if you need to list event accross types. The only thing I will change, is to have a base table (events for instance) with all the shared properties (name, description, date, EventType, etc...) and then have small tables for specific event type properties. On those tables you need an event ID to relate with the master event. You can have a table with Events Types and that way you can easyly add new types of events. This is a bit de-normalized, because the tables with the event specific properties are related to only a subset ot the events table, but in this kind of cases (my opinion) is best to use this kind of schemas.

What i don't understand is why you mention as a Drawnback concern about client filtering speed. You shouldn't do that. For filter event you can always make calls to the server, filter and re-send the filtered information to client.

I hope it helps you and let me know if i can assist you with anything else.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the answer.  Firebase is probably more akin to NoSQL rather than SQL.  It features a hierarchical data structure rather than the traditional relational style SQL DB.  If you're interested in  the key differences, check out [Denormalizing Your Data is Normal](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html). Although there is probably some truth to what you say, I'm going to hold off for an answer that is more Firebase specific, since it is quite different than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I don't fully understand your use case and needs, and talking only in generics here, my first choice for approaches would be a variant of your flat and asymmetrical.

NoSQL is different than SQL in that it allows one to create nested hierarchies, but I have great luck when I stick to a fairly flat structure in most cases, and index things just as I would expect SQL to do so.

Example:

```
/events/$event_id/ (type, name, etc)
/index/by_type/<music|movies|lectures>/$event_id/true
/index/recent/$event_id/true
```

For the `recent` index, I would prioritize the records by `Date`, which would allow me to grab the most recent X records using something like `recentIndexRef.endAt().limit(10)`.

To fetch a list of records from an index, I can do something like the following:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase(URL);

function fetchRecentMusic(numberToFetch, callback) {
   var idxRef = fbRef.child('index/by_type/music').limit(numberToFetch);
   idxRef.once('value', function(snap) {
      var results = [];
      snap.forEach(function(ss) {
         results.push(ss.val());
      });
      callback(results);
   });
}
```

There are, of course, numerous variants on this topic, depending on how real-time this data is and how I want to display it. It also stems into several other advanced topics like [normalizing records through a cache](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/LCa6j/) and [pagination](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/yumaB/).

There are also numerous optimizations to consider once we get into the hundreds of reads per second/millions of records; at that point it might become useful to store a bit of meta data on each index so I don't have to fetch the record for read (such as replacing `true` with the `Name` attribute, for example).

Hope that helps.